# ラムダ式コンストラクタと普通のコンストラクタの違いが知りたいです。

Tags: c#

タイトル通りなのですがクラスのコンストラクタでラムダ式と普通のコンストラクタとの処理の違いが知りたいです。
１、`public string name => "nothing";`はgetアクセ同じですが内部処理などはどう違うのでしょうか？

```
public class SampleLambda
{

    private int num;
    private string[] str_nums = new string[5];
    public string name => "nothing";

    public string this[int key]
    {
        get => str_nums[key];

        set => str_nums[key] = value;
    }


    //public SampleLambda()  => num = 3;

    public SampleLambda()
    {
        num = 3;
    }


    public int Multi(int a) => a * num;

    /*
     * public int Multi(int a)
     * {
     *      return a * num;
     * }      
     */
}

class Program
{

    static void Main()
    {
        var c = new SampleLambda();
        Console.WriteLine(c.name);
        Console.WriteLine(c.Multi(5));

        c[1] = "test";
        Console.WriteLine(c[1]);







        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`public string name => "nothing";`はそもそもプロパティであり、コンストラクターではありません。
[プロパティはC# 6](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-6#expression-bodied-function-members)で、[コンストラクターはC# 7.0](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#more-expression-bodied-members)で拡張された新しい構文です。[糖衣構文](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%B3%96%E8%A1%A3%E6%A7%8B%E6%96%87)であり、機能に違いはありません。

Comment: 質問なのですがプロパティとはメンバーのことでしょうか？